# I cant edit background image. Using The gem theme. Error with custom.css

Tags: php, css, wordpress, website-deployment

I keep getting an error, TheGem's styles cannot be customized because file "/home2/stargbb9/public_html/wp-content/themes/thegem-child/css/custom.css" cannot be modified. Please check your server's settings. Then click "Save Changes" button.

I then edited the .css and function file and still its making me enter my FTP details after saving my changes and resulting in an error outright.

```
---- (style.css)

    /*
    Theme Name: TheGem Child
    Description: Multi-Purpose Wordpress Theme
    Author: Codex Themes.
    Theme URI: http://codex-themes.com/thegem/
    Author URI: http://codex-themes.com/thegem/
    Template: thegem
    Version: 1.0
    Tags: one-column, two-columns, left-sidebar, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, custom-background, custom-colors, custom-header, custom-menu, featured-images, flexible-header, full-width-template, theme-options, translation-ready, dark, light
    License: GNU General Public License
    License URI: license.txt
    */

--- functions.php

    <?php
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
    function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

        $parent_style = 'parent-style'; 

        wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
            array( $parent_style ),
            wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
        );
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: file permissions?

Comment: Yes I can provide my file. Which one do you want to look at? And how can I format my code on stack overflow so its nice to see. (noob question i know). I need to use stack and github more often.

Comment: you can highlight and press ctrl+k to code format, or indent the code at least 4 space or past it indented with tabs or use ` the backtic around it like quotes (for comments or inline `code`). I think knowing the file permissions on your file would be more useful.  Are you editing it and uploading over FTP or editing though WP UI.  Its actually preferable security wise to allow PHP to only read PHP files on the server so it wouldn't shock me if it was readonly. When you edit it in the WP user interface, your using the PHP system user, when you do it over FTP you could be using the C-Panel user

Comment: Both FTP and WP UI

Comment: I dont think i can format code in comment section.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: Ok AP, i think i did it. here is my code. Help me :)